# Prove that $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to show that $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is continuous everywhere using $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$.

In case at point $x=0$, it is easily verified.

But for some other points except $x=0$, How can I choose $\delta$ such that it works for every $\varepsilon$?

Comment: You don't need one $\delta$ for every $\epsilon$. For every $\epsilon$ you need a $\delta$.

Comment: Is $x$ assumed to be nonnegative?

Comment: nope there is no restriction on x

Comment: No restriction on x, interesting!

Answer (score 2):

Note that your function is not defined if $n$ is even and $x<0$.  I'll give an argument when $a>0$ and will leave the rest up to you.

So, let $\epsilon>0$ and choose
$$\delta=\min\Bigl(\frac a2,\,\epsilon n\bigl(\frac a2\bigr)^{(n-1)/n}\Bigr)>0\ .$$
If $|x-a|<\delta$ then
$$x-a>-\frac a2\quad\hbox{so}\quad x>\frac a2>0$$
and
$$\frac{\bigl|x-a\bigr|}{n(\frac a2)^{(n-1)/n}}<\epsilon\ .$$
So we have
$$\eqalign{\bigl|x^{1/n}-a^{1/n}\bigr|
  &=\frac{\bigl|x-a\bigr|}
    {\bigl|x^{(n-1)/n}+x^{(n-2)/n}a^{1/n}+\cdots
     +x^{1/n}a^{(n-2)/n}+a^{(n-1)/n}\bigr|}\cr
  &\le\frac{\bigl|x-a\bigr|}{n(\frac a2)^{(n-1)/n}}\cr
  &<\epsilon\ .\cr}$$
So $x^{1/n}$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: Nice job writing out that goriness

Comment: Thanks but could you explain more how you can break x(1/n)-a^(1/n) into lx-al over something?

Comment: You should already know the factorisation$$p^n-q^n=(p-q)(p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}q+\cdots+pq^{n-2}+q^{n-1})\ ,$$then substitute $p=x^{1/n}$ and $q=a^{1/n}$.

Comment: In case n=odd and x is negative, is the similar argument valid?

Comment: Pretty much.  It won't be completely identical, you will just have to use some absolute values.